# How do I position a CALayer in the center of a UIView in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiview, calayer

I have this CALayer thats a dot that I want to be exactly at the center of the UIView. I have a UIView that covers 2/3 of the screen. How would I get the dot to be in the middle of the UIView. The code below positions the dot an inch above where I need it to be. Here is my code:

```
func setupUI() {

    let lineShape1 = CAShapeLayer()

    let linePath1 = UIBezierPath.init(ovalIn: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5, height: 5))
    lineShape1.path = linePath1.cgPath
    lineShape1.fillColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.7, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
    lineShape1.position = CGPoint(x: cameraView.frame.size.width / 2, y: cameraView.frame.size.height / 2)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(lineShape1)

}
```

Comment: You are not giving enough info. What _is_ `lineShape1`?

Comment: Also if you want to position this thing in the middle `cameraView`, why are you adding it to `self.view`?

Comment: gonna update now

Comment: When I use `cameraView` the dot doesnt show up on the screen for some reason.

Comment: Because you are confusing `frame` and `bounds`. Add the shape layer to the `cameraView` and put it in the middle of `cameraView.bounds`, not `cameraView.frame`.

Comment: I did it like this it didnt work for me: `lineShape1.position = CGPoint(x: cameraView.bounds.size.width / 2, y: cameraView.bounds.size.height / 2)
        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(lineShape1)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216302/discussion-between-xcode22-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing frame and bounds. Set it like this

```
func setupUI() {

    let lineShape1 = CAShapeLayer()

    let linePath1 = UIBezierPath.init(ovalIn: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 5, height: 5))
    lineShape1.path = linePath1.cgPath
    lineShape1.fillColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.7, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
    lineShape1.position = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)
    
   view.layer.addSublayer(lineShape1)

}
```

Comment: Dont I have to use the cameraView instead of the view to get the center of the cameraView?

Comment: are you adding it in view or in camera view ? do you want to center it to view or camera view ?

Comment: I want to center it to the cameraView